# How can I find guest lecturer gigs?

Tags: lecturer

I am an established lecturer, with my own niche area of research. My area should be of interest to lots of Master of Arts (MA) courses in my field—I get good student feedback and it's an interesting topic.

What are good ways of letting organisers of Masters courses in my field know that I am able to provide one-off guest lectures on their courses?

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, I would recommend you write directly to the lecturers in the relevant courses.  They are the ones that will make the content decisions for their own courses.  Some may see your offer as a good way to get some valuable content and presentation in their courses while easing their own workload.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways, but both are long term solutions.

First, you could work to achieve a large (large) circle of collaboration in your field, so that people think of you and, perhaps, invite you for a visit. You might be asked to talk to students as part of a collaborative visit. Some of those might be paid, but not likely very many. Conferences are good for finding people with similar interests. And, with collaborators, you can think in terms of mutual invitations to speak, or even exchanges.

Second, you could work to become so dominant in your field's knowledge base that people you don't know think of you. That could be in academic publications or in the popular literature.  Linus Pauling got a lot of such invitations, for example, as did Paul Erdős. Everyone knows about your accomplishments and wants to hear what you have to say. Carl Sagan was another example.